# Why is this program repeating itself?

Tags: python

I am trying to get a game from exercise 36 in [LPTHW](http://www.learnpythonthehardway.org) to work.

I can get the whole part of the game working except when it gets to the combat. Here is where I think the problem is.

```
def combat_engine():    
    global wins, hit_points, current_hp
    if monster_current_hp or current_hp > 0:
        print "You can type 'a' for attack, or 'q' for quit, choose one."
        answer = raw_input(":> ")
        if 'a' in answer:
            attack(monster)
            attack('player')
            combat_engine()
        elif 'q' in answer:
            print t.white_on_red("You give up and are devoured by the %s.") % monster
            exit(0)
        else:
            print "I dont understand %s." % answer
            next()
            combat_engine() 
    elif monster_hp == 0:
        print "You defeated the %s, congradulations %s!" % monster, name
        wins = wins + 1
        if wins == 5:
            you_win()
        elif victim == 'player':
            hit_points = hit_points + d6()
            current_hp = hit_points
            print "You feel hardier."
            next()
            barracks()
    elif current_hp == 0:
        print "You have been deafeted by the %s, better luck next time." % monster
        next()
        exit(0)

    else: 
        print "Bug Somewhere"
```

I believe the bug is somewhere in this function. When i printed out the HP values of each character, the battle was still going on after the monster had been reduced to -2 hp. maybe it a problem with booleans?

What I would like it to do is to either do all the stat adjustments for winning and quit the game if you lose. I just want to get past this so I can start learning about classes and dicts which should make my life much easier. Please let me know if I should post more information, I'm new at this and not the best at posting questions on here yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try reducing your code sample - remove inessential lines of code until you have only the ones that trigger the bug. This involves getting rid of the actual combat - just see if you can hardcode a sequence of events that leads to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: The reason for this is that your code sample is pretty hard to review by reading, and the process might help you find your bug.

Comment: Im not so sure which lines are innesential to be honest, though i think the problem is in the first 'if' statement on the combat_engine function. Maybe im misunderstanding you? Sucks to be a newb.

Comment: Would it make sense to add to my question where these functions are called and or the output im getting?

Comment: Ok I was able to reduce the sample.

Comment: Having to figure out which lines are innessential is part of the diagnosis process. You can always use trial and error. The idea is to keep removing elements you *think* aren't causing the problem, while preserving the basic structure of the control flow. It doesn't matter if you're correct, but you have to test after every change. If what you remove was not causing the problem, you end up with a simpler manifestation of the bug that's easier to understand and debug. If you remove something and the problem goes away, that means you've just found (part of) the cause!

Comment: The point is to end up knowing more or less exactly where the cause of your problem lies – you now know what to focus on. This will either lead you to fixing the problem yourself, or make this a *much* easier task for the people on SO who read your question. This dramatically increases the likelihood of getting a good answer, quickly. Another fringe benefit is that your question will be less specific to your situation and thus more likely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the last part of your code you don't call the function **d100()**, but the value d100. That's surely not what you want to do.

```
   if d20() >= monster_to_hit and d100() <= monster_crit:
        print "The %s scored a critical hit against you!" % monster
        hit_points = hit_points - (monster_dmg * 3)
        next()
    elif d20 >= monster_to_hit and d100() > crit:
        print "The %s strikes you!"
        hit_points = hit_points - monster_dmg
        next()
```

when debugging in python, the main word is "print". You should feel free to print as much as possible so as to understand what's going on.

example:

```
# attack function
def attack(victim):
    dice20 = d20()
    dice100 = d100()

    print "victim == monster", victim == monster    

    print dice20
    print dice100
    print to_hit
    print crit
    print monster_current_hp
    print mod_dmg 
    print mod_dmg * 3
    print monster_to_hit
    print monster_crit
    print hit_points
    print monster_dmg
    print monster_dmg * 3

    global monster_current_hp, current_hp, to_hit, crit, hit_points
    if victim == monster:
        if dice20 >= to_hit and dice100 <= crit:
            print "You scored a critical hit against the %s!" % monster
            monster_current_hp = monster_current_hp - (mod_dmg * 3)
            next()
        elif dice20 >= to_hit and dice100 > crit:
            print "You strike the %s!" % monster
            monster_current_hp = monster_current_hp - mod_dmg
            next()
        else:
            print "The %s evades your attack!" % monster
            next()
    else:
        if dice20 >= monster_to_hit and dice100 <= monster_crit:
            print "The %s scored a critical hit against you!" % monster
            hit_points = hit_points - (monster_dmg * 3)
            next()
        elif dice20 >= monster_to_hit and dice100 > crit:
            print "The %s strikes you!"
            hit_points = hit_points - monster_dmg
            next()
```

do the same in the combat engine so as to see the infinite loop appear. Then remove the useless print that bloat your trace with unuseful information, until you see clearly the reason it loops, because of some value, because of a boolean if test that doesn't behave the way you expected... something like that.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. Doesn't seem fix my issue but i totally missed that.

Comment: the key point for debbuging in Python is to put print of values. In each of you comparison, add print to understand the logic behind. I'm gonna edit show you the 'debug' print I would have add to examine the traces.

Comment: This has helped to understand whats going on better, I'll expand in an edit

Answer (score 2):

`if monster_current_hp or current_hp > 0:` is flawed in two ways: first, it's just testing whether monster_current_hp evaluates to true, not testing it against 0; second, even if that were fixed, the statement will continue the program if EITHER fighter has positive HP, whereas presumably you want to stop when either fighter has negative hp.  Try this instead: `if monster_current_hp > 0 and current_hp > 0:`

Once you do that, you'll start getting to the "bug somewhere" line in most cases.  That's because `elif monster_hp == 0:` and `elif current_hp == 0:` will not trigger when HP goes straight from positive to negative.  Use `<=` in both of those cases to catch instances where HP is negative.